# Bootstrap margin space on right of header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width, margin

So I am making my first Bootstrap site, and I have what looks like a simple problem to fix, but I just cannot for the life of me fine the code which is coursing the problem. On the right hand side of the page I am getting about 20px of margin which should not be there, and it's happening in all browsers. Could someone take a quick look at my site to see what the problem might be, because I just cannot find it.

http://www.waynegrant.net/test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 20px of padding on `.row-fluid.foot`.

```
/*main.css:179*/
.row-fluid.foot {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You, my friend are a star. Thank you.